# Run script on shutdown of machine

Tags: 18.04, git

Is there a good way to run a shutdown hook when I shutdown my Ubuntu 18.04 machine? I need to a run a script that might take about 30 seconds, to be specific pushing to git remotes any dangling changes.

Comment: What you're asking is basically a duplicate, a more specifically this: https://askubuntu.com/a/795406/295286  Personally, I'd do it the other way around, make a script/function that pushes stuff first, then calls shutdown.